# Best way to get data image for processing

Tags: objective-c, ios, image-processing, core-graphics, convolution

i want to get data from uiimage to read rgb values. I want to use this data for convolution filters. In the internet i found only one method:

```
// First get the image into your data buffer
CGImageRef image = [UIImage CGImage];
NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(image);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
unsigned char *rawData_ = malloc(height * width * 4);
NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel_ * width;
NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height, bitsPerComponent,           bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height));
CGContextRelease(context);

// Now your rawData contains the image data in the RGBA8888 pixel format.
int byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * yy) + xx * bytesPerPixel;
red = rawData[byteIndex];
green = rawData[byteIndex + 1];
blue = rawData[byteIndex + 2];
alpha = rawData[byteIndex + 3];
```

Its ok but i want to working with pixels on array some like this: [x][y][r,b,g].

How Can i solve it?

Answer (score 1):

There's another way to get the image data: [Technical Q&A QA1509: Getting the pixel data from a CGImage object](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1509/_index.html)

As to how you access it, you don't have much choice. Multi-dimensional C arrays can only work when the second and subsequent dimensions have a fixed size known at compile time. The image data does not.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative suggestion, I'd recommend not doing an image convolution on the CPU. Instead, I have a variety of GPU-based convolutions within my [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework that can be an order of magnitude faster than CPU-bound implementations.

These include a heavily optimized GPUImageSobelEdgeDetectionFilter, which performs Sobel edge detection on the luminance of an image, and the GPUImage3x3ConvolutionFilter, which lets you supply a generic 3x3 convolution kernel to apply to an arbitrary image. For live video, these can easily process incoming frames in realtime. For UIImages, these filters can run 6-10X faster than convolutions performed on the CPU.

Per your specific question, Ken's suggestion is a good one, but in practice I've found that the data copying approach Apple suggests in the linked article actually ends up being slower than redrawing the image in a bitmap context. This seems odd, but I get consistent results to this effect in my benchmarks. The Core Graphics drawing that you present above is the fastest way I've found to access raw UIImage pixel data.